# True result in worksheet, but False result in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

While debugging I entered the following into the immediate window:

```
?Cells(CurrentRow, 6).value = Cells(TopDrawerFrontRow, 6 + i * 2).value
False

?WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Cells(CurrentRow, 6))
True

?Cells(CurrentRow, 6)
 105.2 

?WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Cells(TopDrawerFrontRow, 6 + i * 2))
True

?Cells(TopDrawerFrontRow, 6 + i * 2)
 105.2
```

And when I entered a formula to compare the two cells in the worksheet, the result is true.
A real headscratcher...

Plus, there is not 1, but 5 105.2 values on the row I'm looping through.
False every time in VBA. True every time when entering a formula (such as =F47=N46) in the worksheet.

All cells are formatted as numbers. All numbers numbers rounded to the nearest .1 and values copy and pasted to static, so there are no hidden digits.

```
Match = False
            
            For i = 1 To 6
                If Cells(CurrentRow, 6) = Cells(TopDrawerFrontRow, 6 + i * 2) And Match = False Then
                    If Cells(TopDrawerFrontRow, 6 + i * 2).Interior.Color <> green Or Cells(TopDrawerFrontRow, 5) = "split" Then
                        Match = True
                        Cells(TopDrawerFrontRow, 6 + i * 2).Interior.Color = green
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
```

Comment: `If Cells(CurrentRow, 6) = Round(Cells(TopDrawerFrontRow, 6 + i * 2),1)`

Comment: ^^^ Sounds like floating-point error.

Comment: @ScottCraner Negative.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: `If Round(Cells(CurrentRow, 6),1) = Round(Cells(TopDrawerFrontRow, 6 + i * 2),1)`

Comment: If it were a rounding issue, wouldn't all the hidden digits show up in the immediate window?

Comment: Hmmm... interesting that Round() in VBA doesn't work, but using Mround in the spreadsheet formulas fixed it.  But if anything were different, I would've expected FALSE in the spreadsheet too.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think without more information, and data samples, we can only guess at what's going on.

Comment: Try CDbl() around each number. Excel might be giving you strings on some, which would make comparisons always false because "1" = 1 is false when comparing cell values.